# How to run Adobe AIR Application on Apple iPad?

Tags: flash, ipad, air, adobe

I am Adobe Flash Designer\Developer and i ended AIR Application for desktop and need to know how to launch this app on iPad?

Comment: Take a look at the Forum: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/872270

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to port the Application to an AIR Mobile app to get it to run on the iPad.  Ttis can be easier said than done depending on what you are using. If it is pure a pure ActionScript project then it will probably be easier than if you are using Flex/MXML components that are not optimized for mobile.

You may want/need to create new views for the mobile platform as well.

Additionally you will then probably need to change some things for specific mobile support. Will your app support rotation of the device? Will you want gesture support? Shake support?  Are you using the Encrypted Local Store (Not supported in AIR Mobile 2.x, will be supported in AIR 3.0)?

You'll also have to test the performance on an actual device. The iPad is considerably slower than your average desktop computer.   Does your app do anything memory or processor intensive that could make the iPad freeze up for an extended period.

Here is an article on considerations for AIR for Mobile that you may want to look at: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/considerations-air-apps-mobile.html

Here are some iOS Considerations: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/ios.html

Finally, here is a section of the Adobe AIR for Flash Developers documentation that you'll want to look at: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-8000.html

Good luck. :)